# Is my javascript good for google maps API?

Tags: javascript, css, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, squarespace

I'm using squarespace to build my website and want to insert a custom map from google maps javascript api. I've followed tutorial from W3school and from Google's own tutorial to build my map and follow steps as below :

What I'm trying to archive is a map like this 
[google map example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l5xEk.jpg)

**Step 1**: Insert a embed block for html

```
<div id= "map"></div>
```

**Step 2**: insert javascript in page header

```
<script
src="http://maps.google.cn/maps/api/js?key=my-key">
</script>

<script type="text/javascript">
function initMap() {
  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById(‘map'), {
    zoom: 12,
    center: {lat: 48.877412, lng: 2.359221},
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
  });

  // Define the LatLng coordinates for the polygon's path.
  var 10th = [
    {lat: 48.883863,  lng: 2.349500},
    {lat: 48.870752,  lng: 2.347915},
    {lat: 48.867593,  lng: 2.363981},
    {lat: 48.872958,  lng: 2.377065},
    {lat: 48.877800,  lng: 2.370605},
    {lat: 48.882765,  lng: 2.370164},
    {lat: 48.884218,  lng: 2.368480},
    {lat: 48.884670,  lng: 2.360258},
    {lat: 48.883863,  lng: 2.349500}
  ];

  // Construct the polygon.
  var 10th = new google.maps.Polygon({
    paths: triangleCoords,
    strokeColor: '#FF0000',
    strokeOpacity: 0.8,
    strokeWeight: 2,
    fillColor: '#FF0000',
    fillOpacity: 0.35
  });
  10th.setMap(map);

}
</script>
```

**Step 3** : in custom css section

```
#googleMap {
width: 100%;
height: 380px;
}
```

But so far, I got either a blank page once javascript injected or error page (with code visible on top of the page... )

Here the link to my webpage on SquareSpace https://handa-cheng-a3wm.squarespace.com/1starrondissement

Thanks !

Comment: `google.maps.Map(document.getElementById(‘map')` I guess error is in fancy comma of this function arguments. It should be `google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map')`

Comment: Thanks !
Didn't even notice the weird comma ! But still not working (no error message or anything, just nothing happened..)

Answer (score 0):

You have few typos in your code:

```
var 10th = [...]  // invalid variable name
    ^---
```

Variables names in JavaScript must not begin with numbers. And you have defined the function but didn't run it.

You have not set height for `#map` in css.

```
<div id= "map"></div>

#googleMap { // <== this is not correct id as used in html above
  width: 100%;
  height: 380px;
}
```

```js
function initMap() {
  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
    zoom: 12,
    center: {lat: 48.877412, lng: 2.359221},
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
  });

  // Define the LatLng coordinates for the polygon's path.
  var points = [
    {lat: 48.883863,  lng: 2.349500},
    {lat: 48.870752,  lng: 2.347915},
    {lat: 48.867593,  lng: 2.363981},
    {lat: 48.872958,  lng: 2.377065},
    {lat: 48.877800,  lng: 2.370605},
    {lat: 48.882765,  lng: 2.370164},
    {lat: 48.884218,  lng: 2.368480},
    {lat: 48.884670,  lng: 2.360258},
    {lat: 48.883863,  lng: 2.349500}
  ];

  // Construct the polygon.
  var polygon = new google.maps.Polygon({
    paths: points,
    strokeColor: '#FF0000',
    strokeOpacity: 0.8,
    strokeWeight: 2,
    fillColor: '#FF0000',
    fillOpacity: 0.35
  });
  polygon.setMap(map);

}

 initMap();
```

```css
#map {
  height: 300px;
}
```

```html
<script
src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js">
</script>

<div id="map"></div>
```